# Jupyter notebook jump down even if it is not exceuted

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have jupyter notebook 7.1.0 and Python 3.11.5. I did not have this problem with the older version of the notebook: Sometimes, I cannot access the top cells of a Jupyter notebook, and it keeps jumping down! Even if I drag the scroller to the top, it jumps down and does not let me see the top cells! It happens regardless of whether the cell is active, running, or idle. Any idea how to fix this issue instead of installing the older version?